# Increment a square in a 2D list while decrementing all the others squares not involved - Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pycharm, chess

i have a 2D list, and im trying to update the value of a cell, while i have to decrement the values of the other cells i'm not incrementing.

i have a 2D list called

```
PAWN = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

And in my code i'm updating all the square that involve a pawn move, for example, g3, h4, the matrix will update like this, adding a 0,1 for the move, and this works quite fine.

```
PAWN = [
       A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
   8  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   7  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   6  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   5  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   4  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1],
   3  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0],
   2  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   1  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

Here's snippet of my code:

```
white_moves = ['g3', 'h4']
    for moves in white_moves:
        delta = 0.1
        if len(moves) == 2: # for example g3
            y = moves[0]   #y = g
            x = int(moves[1]) #x = 3

            coordinate = {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f', 6: 'g', 7: 'h'}
            c = coordinate.values()
            for key, value in coordinate.items():
                if y == value:
                    indice_colonna = key
                
            for letter in c:  
                if letter == y:  # if value in dictionary is equal to my y

   
                    file = open('../data/tables/pedone.csv', 'r') #reading from csv file
                    reader = csv.reader(file)
                    PAWN = list(reader)
                    file.close()
                    new_pawn = PAWN    
    
                    new_pawn[8-x][indice_colonna] = round(float(PAWN[8-x][indice_colonna]) + delta, 1) #here im incrementing the value of square [g][3]
    
    
                    new_pawn = open("../data/tables/pedone.csv", 'w', newline='') #updating that file
                    writer = csv.writer(new_pawn)
                    writer.writerows(PAWN)
                    new_pawn.close()
                    break
```

How i can decrement all the other squares? from row 0 to 8 and column 0 to 8 but avoiding to decrement also the g3 square? im having troubles separating this two operations

here what i've tried:

```
rows = 8
columns = 8

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        pedone[i][j] = -0.1
        pedone[8-x][indice_colonna] = + 2*0.1 #trying to add 2x the value
```

but doesnt works, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are both removing `-0.1`  from each cell (which is ok) and at each iteration you are adding `+ 2*0.1` to the target cell. However, you want to add `+ 2*0.1` only once!

Try this:

```py
rows = 8
columns = 8

pedone[8-x][indice_colonna] += 2*0.1 #trying to add 2x the value  ONE TIME ONLY

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        pedone[i][j] = -0.1
```

Comment: thanks, now it makes sense, but still isn't the best solution, there is a way to tell python "update this row/col/ while decrementing all the others?"

Comment: something like "remove from rows and columns, row = 3, and columns = g" but for all possible moves in white_moves

Comment: Ok there was also a typo. You wrote `= + 2*0.1` which means "assign 0.2" instead of `+= 2*0.1` which means to update the value. Have a try now.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop trying to add 2x the value, you overwrite the entire matrix every time you iterate, and only set a single value to .2. You will want to split these up and then apply the operation. In addition, if you were incrementing the value, it would increase every time you go through the loop.

This would require you to read the CSV into a matrix at the start, and write it at the end, rather than repeatedly writing to it, unless you want to subtract a value on every possible move rather than just once.

```
rows = 8
columns = 8

# read CSV into pedone

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        pedone[i][j] -= 0.1

# and then enter your loop:
for moves in white_moves
    ...
        pedone[8-x][indice_colonna] += 2 * 0.1

# write pedone back to CSV
```

Comment: sadly i will have a huge database of moves, so i think that is not good to update 2*delta the chose move, i need something that does both...